# Is there a way to get gerrit replication to use Kerberos authentication to push as the user submitting?

Tags: replication, kerberos, gerrit

I am looking at setting up gerrit as a CI gate/review system, and would like to push any reviewed and ultimately submitted commits to another git system.  So far so simple, we have replication.

But...  The authentication into gerrit would be using Kerberos, and the authentication into the server I want to push to would also be using Kerberos.

I don't see any clear way to get gerrit to propagate the Kerberos authentication on a push that it received into the push from replication.  Is this possible?  If so, where should I read up on the details of how to configure this?

I'm hoping it's possible.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution directly for Gerrit in Java?

Comment: Directly in gerrit would be preferable, but if there are other ways to accomplish it, that could also work, I guess.

Comment: Who is accepting the SPNEGO security context? Some Java valve on Tomcat/Jetty?

Comment: I'm unclear which part of the setup you are referring to.  I haven't actually got it setup yet, but the authentication to gerrit would certainly be in gerrit (on the ssh connection) I would expect.

On the other end, it's on a remote git server, which I do not run.

What I'm looking for is a way to take the creds used when submitting reviewed code, and apply them to the outbound replication.  If I need to do this externally and create my own replication, that could possibly work, but I'd need a way to get the kerberos creds out of gerrit, no?

Comment: So it is obvioulsy not a question for SO. Serverfault or superuser. Without knowning your setup, I can' give you any proper advise.